# Working with @ConfigurationProperties in a non Spring-Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to get configuration-binding in my Spring-MVC application (non Spring-Boot) enabled using the @ConfigurationProperties. The only thing i did so far, is that I added the Maven `spring-boot` dependency to my project, to get the `ConfigurationProperties` class.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
public class FooConfig{

  private String bar;
  // ...  
}
```

So far nothing is being bound. Any thoughts to get the binding going?

Comment: Did you use `@EnableConfigurationProperties`

Comment: Thanks, this was missing to get it started. This is the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to Enable Configuration Properties.

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
```