# @ConfigurationProperties in Spring not springboot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

We have SpringMVC application on Spring 5. Saw @ConfigurationProperties from springboot automatically handles Profiling based on the environment we set in applications.properties. I have a restriction using springboot dependencies with springMVC. Is there any way can leverage this functionality from spring 5 not from springboot?

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639412/working-with-configurationproperties-in-a-non-spring-boot-application/48639608#48639608

Comment: Thanks for your response. It still @EnableConfigurationProperties refers in springboot jar. Looking similar functionality not from springboot.

Comment: sorry misunderstood your question. there is no way to do that. you have to use springboot dependency

Comment: Thank you for the response appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <version>xxxx</version> 
</dependency>
```

You can add dependency above fragment of maven pom in your spring project.

My project was spring project but no springboot. And at the same time, I also want to use `@EnableConfigurationProperties` functional. So I just add `spring-boot-autoconfigure` in my project.